# Blender is not running in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: blender

I have downloaded Blender 2.68 from official website.
After extracting the zipped file,earlier I was able to run it by simply clicking the 'blender' executable file in the folder.

But now, whenever I try to run it by clicking the executable file. It gives error as:

> **Could not display "/home/anuj/blender-2.68a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender".** 
>   There is
>   no application installed for executable files. Do you want to search
>   for an application to open this file?